# CodePipeline empty bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a simple CodePipeline that uses CodeCommit repo as source and upload all the files to S3 bucket on push event. However if I delete a file from the CodeCommit it doesn't delete it on the bucket (which is expected). That's why I need to have a stage that empty all the bucket files prior to extract the new ones from CodeCommit. Is it possible to do so? The workaround that I have in mind is to create a lambda function that deletes all the objects in the bucket and then invoke it on the pipeline stage. Please advise!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What's your question? Add an action that empties the bucket before proceeding.

Comment: Yes, without using any third party lambda

Comment: So just add a codebuild action that does it with aws cli.